# Why is TS complaining that object is possibly null when I explicitly wrapped it in an `if`?

Tags: typescript

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {

    state = {error: null, errorInfo: null};

    componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: React.ErrorInfo) {
        this.setState({
            error: error,
            errorInfo: errorInfo
        })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.errorInfo) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h2>Something went wrong.</h2>
                    <pre>
                        <code>
                            {String(this.state.error)}
                            {this.state.errorInfo.componentStack} // <-- error is here
                        </code>
                    </pre>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return this.props.children;
    }
}
```

Message is:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/ErrorBoundary.tsx:22:30 
>       TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

[image]

But the `if` block won't execute if `this.state.errorInfo` is `null`, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Even if I write it like this:

```
 {this.state.errorInfo !== null ? this.state.errorInfo.componentStack : 'hello'}
```

or

```
 {this.state && this.state.errorInfo ? this.state.errorInfo.componentStack : 'hello'}
```

I get the same error.

---

tsconfig for good measure:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "importHelpers": false,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "module": "ES6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "lib": ["es2018","dom"],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "target": "es2018",
        "declaration": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": false,
        "esModuleInterop": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "files": [
        "src/index.tsx"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/types/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that

```
state = {error: null, errorInfo: null};
```

overrides the `state`'s type. The inferred type of errorInfo is always `null`
You can correct it by giving the type explicitly:

```
state: { error: Error | null, errorInfo: React.ErrorInfo | null } =
{ error: null, errorInfo: null };
```

This issue is reported and discussed here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10570

Comment: Alternatively, `error: null as Error | null` etc. which is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

I was still seeing this issue when using a state variable inside a `map`.

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.foo) { return <Loading /> }

    [1,2,3].map(n => {
        this.state.foo.property; // Object possibly null
    }

    ...
}
```

I solved this by:

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.foo) { return <Loading /> }

    const foo = this.state.foo;

    [1,2,3].map(n => {
        foo.property; // Cool!
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

state update is asynchronous and u shouldnt rely on it to be updated before rendering.

you should read more about [React component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

if u dont wanna use redux (this is also debatable - redux is complex and u should use it only when u need it, but state manipulation is not easy so u should use it anyway)

with that said... just simply perform a conditional check before u read from it (again async)

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {init: here};
}
```

> You should not call setState() in the constructor(). Instead, if your component needs to use local state, assign the initial state to this.state directly in the constructor.
>
> Constructor is the only place where you should assign this.state directly. In all other methods, you need to use this.setState() instead.

Comment: (1) I'm not calling `setState` in the constructor, (2) I absolutely need `componentDidCatch`, that's the entire purpose of an "error boundary" component, (3) I'm not relying on a state update before rendering (hence the `if`), and (4) none of this had to do with my question, which is a compile-time error to do with TypeScript syntax.

Comment: you initial state was wrong, all the other info was extra

https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010

Comment: What do you mean my initial state was wrong?Putting the state outside the ctor does exactly the same thing: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgCYgGYEMCuAbRBjbdAZyIQFEYZYAhKTAOyXRgE8Fw4RHSAlEdPHAB0AYSgBbaPS6IA3sASKEROOk4IAvAlkhKsAFwJ6ObABp2emAEl6qKIePZsAXwDcwZ0A&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2017%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=Node-10&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2